# Elements in GF(5^2) - Am I understanding this correctly?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

For a finite field GF(2^m), there are 2^m polynomials and the degree of each is no more than m-1.

Can this be applied to GF(5^2)? Would GF(5^2) have 25 elements where each element has a degree no greater than 1?

Would said 25 elements be:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)  
(D, D+1, D+2, D+3, D+4)  
(2D, 2D+1, 2D+2, 2D+3, 2D+4)  
(3D, 3D+1, 3D+2, 3D+3, 3D+4)  
(4D, 4D+1, 4D+2, 4D+3, 4D+4)
```

?

Comment: What is $D$ ? (it isn't defined in the post.)

Comment: I assume it means x or something. I found it here: http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/crypto/playing_with_gf(3%5E2).htm

Answer (score 0):

I had to look twice, thrice, more, to understand what you were saying. Here’s a restatement, with the field GF(q) denoted instead as $\Bbb F_q$:

If $\Bbb F_{2^m}=\Bbb F_2(\rho)$, i.e. if $\rho$ is an element of $\Bbb F_{2^m}$ whose minimal $\Bbb F_2$-polynomial is of degree $m$, then every element of $\Bbb F_{2^m}$ may be written $a_0+a_1\rho+\cdots+a_{m-1}\rho^{m-2}$, the $a_i$ all lying in $\Bbb F_2$. So the polynomial expressions you were talking about must be polynomials in a special kind of element $\rho$ of $\Bbb F_{2^m}$.

This is basic field theory, and applies, *mutatis mutandis* to any finite-degree field extension, in particular to $\Bbb F_5\subset\Bbb F_{25}$. So what you say is correct, as long as $D$ is root of an irreducible quadratic polynomial over $\Bbb F_5$. For instance, your polynomial could be $X^2-3$, since $3$ is not a square in $\Bbb F_5$.

Comment: So the 25 elements I listed are correct (substituting x in for D)?

Comment: @Juan They are correct if $D$ is a root of an irreducible quadratic over $\mathbb F_5,$ like Lubin said. "I assume it means $x$ or something" isn't sufficient cause you need to know how to multiply those linear polynomials together and get *linear* polynomials rather than higher degree (so your field is closed under multiplication). This means quotienting out by a quadratic polynomial. In order to test your understanding, don't just write out the elements of the field, write out their multiplication table.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and amplification, @spaceisdarkgreen